# Join in query .. with if control: is it possible?

Tags: sql

I've this db structure:

```
Message  

msg_by     usertype     message    
2             U         how are you ? 
1             A         i'm fine


SimpleUser 

id          fullname    
1           mike    
2           john


AdminUser    

id           fullname
1            frank     
2            lucas
```

Ok, i know it's not correct to split users into two table but i've inherited this project.

My question is how to make a query making joining Message with SimpleUser and AdminUser ... with the result to have the correct name for each message based  to usertype: if U the message is from SimpleUser table, if A the message is from AdminUser

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a `UNION`:

```
SELECT fullname, message FROM msg_by JOIN SimpleUser ON(msg_by = SimpleUser.id)
  WHERE usertype = "U"

UNION ALL

SELECT fullname, message FROM msg_by JOIN AdminUser ON(msg_by = AdminUser.id)
  WHERE usertype = "A"
```

Comment: Notes: Using UNION to create an inline view (rather than combine the results) *may* be faster, and is probably more generic and portable.  And using UNION ALL is almost certainly faster.  All the same, +1 :)

Comment: @Dems: Thanks! `UNION ALL` is even better, edited! And the suggestion of the inline view may be useful to the OP in other situations anyway, given that she said the database is "inherited".

Answer (score 4):

This is one query which will return the rows you want:

```
SELECT
  msg_by, usertype, message, full_name
FROM
  Message
INNER JOIN
  SimpleUser
ON
  SimpleUser.id = Message.msg_by 
AND 
  Message.usertype = 'U'

UNION ALL

SELECT
  msg_by, usertype, message, full_name
FROM
  Message
INNER JOIN
  AdminUser
ON
  AdminUser.id = Message.msg_by 
AND 
  Message.usertype = 'A'
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need union. You can add the usertype to the join:

```
select
  m.*,
  ifnull(a.full_name, s.full_name)
from
  Message m
  left join AdminUser a on a.id = m.msg_by and m.usertype = 'A'
  left join SimpleUser s on s.id = m.msg_by and m.usertype = 'U'
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like that:

```
SELECT m.message, COALESCE(s.fullname, a.fullname)
FROM Message m
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SimpleUser s
        ON m.usertype = 'U'
        AND m.msg_by = s.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN AdminUser a
        ON m.usertype = 'A'
        AND m.msg_by = a.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, my natural inclination would be to use the LEFT JOIN approach.

In consideration, however, the UNION approach may be best - if laid out as an inline view instead...

```
SELECT
  Message.*,
  User.*
FROM
  Message
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT *, 'A' as UserType From AdminUsers
  UNION ALL
  SELECT *, 'U' AS UserType FROM SimpleUsers
)
  AS User
    ON  User.UserType = Message.UserType
    AND User.ID       = Message.msg_by
```

Using this inline-view layout *may* result in better performance, due to only needing to scan the Message table once.

It also directs you towards the option of creating a real view to unify your two tables.

Comment: It may perform better, but it may be slower as well, because the inner join on Message and the subselect may not be able to utilize indexes. But as you say, testing (and checking explain plans) will answer to any doubts. :)

Comment: In my experience, using UNION ALL in this way would maintain the use of INDEXes.  Use of UNION (and it's de-deuplication) can be a different matter because of it's de-duplication routines.  It does, however, all depend on the RDBMS's engine, and the best way to know, is to test :)